# SQL Query/ Assigning Rank

Tags: sql, oracle

I am interested in SQL query not the PLSQL code.

> We need to assign the rank based on date and id value
>
> Input table should look like below

```
+------------+----+
|    date    | id |
+------------+----+
| 01-01-2018 | A  |
| 02-01-2018 | A  |
| 03-01-2018 | C  |
| 04-01-2018 | B  |
| 05-01-2018 | A  |
| 06-01-2018 | C  |
| 07-01-2018 | C  |
| 08-01-2018 | B  |
| 09-01-2018 | B  |
| 10-01-2018 | B  |
+------------+----+
```

> output table should look like below

```
+------------+----+------+
|    date    | id | rank |
+------------+----+------+
| 01-01-2018 | A  |    1 |
| 02-01-2018 | A  |    2 |
| 03-01-2018 | C  |    1 |
| 04-01-2018 | B  |    1 |
| 05-01-2018 | A  |    1 |
| 06-01-2018 | C  |    1 |
| 07-01-2018 | C  |    2 |
| 08-01-2018 | B  |    1 |
| 09-01-2018 | B  |    2 |
| 10-01-2018 | B  |    3 |
+------------+----+------+
```

Comment: should not the second record be (02-01-2018,A,50)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you explain the logic for this output? How can this row: `09-01-2018 | B  |    40` become `09-01-2018 | B  |     0`?

Comment: trying to do the lag of id then assigning 0 and 1 if its equal or not. After that i am stuck.   ```select date,
id, value
case when id = lag(id,1) over(order by date) then 1 else 0 end rnk 
    from abc```

Comment: Edit your question and explain (better) what you want.

Comment: @forpas we dont have to assign the rank based on value column. once i will get the rank. then i will do further calculation with value.  Thanks

Comment: @forpas i have edit the question. please take a look. i need a rank. based on id but date should be considered as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  In this case, the simplest solution is probably the difference of row numbers:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by id, (seqnum - seqnum_i)
                          order by date
                         ) as ranking
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date) as seqnum_i
      from t
     ) t;
```

Why this works is a little tricky to explain.  The difference of the two row numbers assigns a constant value to advance values of the same `id`.  If you stare at the results of the subquery, you will see how this works.

Then the outer  query just uses `row_number()` to assign the sequential number you want.